# Xcode 6.3 bot will not code sign the app and there is not an install button

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots

I get the following warning as a Build Service Issue in the new bot I created in Xcode 6.3:

*Bot Issue: warning. Build Service Error.
Issue: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID*

On the server, I can build the app, make the archive and sign it and put it on a device.  I already tried removing the developer account and adding it back; same results.  I want to be able to install the app and save the archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the server to make a build by changing the project settings.  I changed the code signing identity to iOS Developer, deleted the bot and made it again, this time it worked.

Here's what it looks like now: [image]